# ERROR Error: "[object Object]" - Login

Tags: angular

Hola estoy haciendo un login y para ello estoy siguiendo un tutorial, pero al a hora de ir a mi componente /login me dice en la consola del navegador

**ERROR Error: "[object Object]"**

Sin embargo en la terminal no me tira ningún error, el componente del login es el siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.login('peter@klaven', 'cityslicka').subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res); 
      });
  }

  logIn(username: string, password: string, event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Avoid default action for the submit button of the login form

    // Calls service to login user to the api rest
    this.loginService.login(username, password).subscribe(

      res => {
       console.log(res);

      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);

      },

      () => this.navigate()
    );

  }

  navigate() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
}
```

El @Component lo he omitido ya que es lógico, también he creado un servicio que se llama login.service.ts y un login.component.html para hacer el furmulario de inicio de sesión ya ahí me he quedado por que me tiraba el error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(username:string, password:string) {
    return this.http.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
      email: username,
      password: password,     
    });     
  }
}
```

El tutorial que estoy siguiendo es el siguiente: https://codingpotions.com/angular-login-sesion/

Comment: Tiene pinta de que backend te devuelve un error, quizá el usuario es incorrecto. ¿Has probado a ver el objeto que te devuelven? Sustituye `console.error(error)` por `console.error(JSON.stringify(error))`

Comment: @PabloLozano me dice lo mismo, object object :/ yo directamente no puedo acceder al formulario para hacer login

Comment: Si en la consola del navegador se muestra "[object Object]", es porque el código lo está escribiendo. Mira qué línea lo escribe y pon un *breakpoint* ahí

Comment: ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
    Angular 8
        resolvePromise
        resolvePromise
        scheduleResolveOrReject
        invokeTask
        onInvokeTask
        invokeTask
        runTask
        drainMicroTaskQueue  || Supongo que es la línea 8

Comment: Si borro todo mi login.component.ts si que me carga

Comment: Y más exactamente si borro la línea  " **private loginService: LoginService,**" alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: puedes montar un [mcve] en Stackblitz? Sin ver todo el código no me hago una idea de qué te está pasando

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5s113c

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95712/discussion-between-pablo-lozano-and-miguel-angel-martin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente para solucionar el problema en el **login.service.ts** modifiqué el **@Injectable** y lo puse de la siguiente manera:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error suele lanzarlos al hacer un console.log() con alguna de las variables req o res. Yo lo soluciono parseando la variable antes de enviarla con: JSON.stringify(res), prueba y espero que vaya bien.